# Codename One: How to calculate a running total for each button iteration?

Tags: codenameone, cumulative-sum

I would like to calculate a running total each time a button is pressed. It should add up a quantity plus the total quantity (if the button has already been pressed). The following is my code snippet.

```
TextField quantity = new TextField("", "Volume of water (ml)", 4, TextArea.ANY);
intake.addComponent(quantity);

Button add = new Button("Add");
intake.addComponent(add);

...

int total = 0;

//--------------------------------------------------------------
add.addActionListener((ActionEvent ev) -> {
Storage s = Storage.getInstance();

try {

    String num = quantity.getText();
    Integer num2 = Integer.parseInt(num);

    String name = itemName.getText();

    total += num2;
    Dialog.show("", "You have consumed a total of " + Integer.toString(total) + "ml of water", "OK", "Close");

... 

} catch {
    ... 
}

});
```

With the above code, an error ("local variable referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final") occurs for the  code snippet below. I have also tried with the "public void actionPerformed()" method, but with no success

```
total += num2;
Dialog.show("", "You have consumed a total of " + Integer.toString(total) + "ml of water", "OK", "Close");
```

As a result, I would appreciate any help and guidance on how to code a running total.

Answer (score 2):

You might use a method as alternative, such as increaseTotal that will be called instead of manipulating the total variable directly. Just as Shai mentioned event cannot happen in parallel, so no need to bother adding synchronized tag or else.

```
public void increaseTotal(int addedValue){
     this.total += addedValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `total` a member of your class. Since the lambda (the event call) might occur in parallel changing total from within the lambda could produce an illegal state (technically events can't happen in parallel but the Java compiler doesn't know that and disallows non-final access).